# Непонятные отступы в шапке сайта

Tags: header, float, отступы

Всем привет. В верстке новенький, нашел макет чтобы потренироваться, но вот появились трудности уже в шапке сайта. Есть логотип слева, посередине меню и справа телефон и кнопка обратной связи.

[image: Шапка сайта]
Вот что получилось у меня

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
  src: url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: normal;
 width: 100%;
}
header {
 width: 1500px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}
header li {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 background: red;
}
.header__feedback {
 display: inline-block;
 background: red;
 float: right;
 width: 200px;
 height: 80px;
}
.header__logo {
 display: inline-block;
 background: red;
 float: left;
}
.header__feedback_icon img {
 width: 18px;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Тренировка</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <nav>
   <div class="header__logo">
    <img src="img/logo2.png" alt="Logo">
   </div>
   <div class="header__menu_list">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Инфраструктура</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Планировки и цены</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Материалы и отделка</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Документы</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="header__feedback">
    <div class="header__feedback_number">
     + 7 (495) 544-23-12
    </div>
    <div class="header__feedback_icon">
     <img src="img/icon_phone.png" alt="icon">
    </div>
    <div class="header__feedback_button"> 
     <a href="#">Заказать звонок</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Мне нужно блок с обратной связью поместить вправо. Но он почему то становится ниже списка. И сверху непонятный отступ, хотя у body обнулены отступы. Как решить проблему посоветуйте пожалуйста..

Answer (score 1):

```
.header__menu_list {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помог!)) Я так понимаю, чтобы выстроить в линию несколько блоков, нужно каждому задать display: inline-block?

Comment: @Roman, .header__menu_list тег у него по дефолту block, а значит ширина блока занимает всю ширину родителя, так как он стоит после логотипа у которого задан float, позиционируется он от него

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, тебе нужно **это**:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```